# Geolocation for openlayers Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

Helo, I want to try "[OpenLayers Explorer Example](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/olexp)" with geolocation and zoom my position, but "[geolocation example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html)" from openlayers dont work for me. What im doing wrong to show my position on map?

I got a message from google chrome if i want Enable Location Services, but I dont see the marker on map.

This code I added to [standalone.html](https://github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/olexp/blob/master/docs/examples/standalone.html) as example

```
<script>
  var view = new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  });

  var map = new Map({
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: view
  });

  var geolocation = new Geolocation({
    // enableHighAccuracy must be set to true to have the heading value.
    trackingOptions: {
      enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    projection: view.getProjection()
  });

  function el(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  el('track').addEventListener('change', function() {
    geolocation.setTracking(this.checked);
  });

  // update the HTML page when the position changes.
  geolocation.on('change', function() {
    el('accuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAccuracy() + ' [m]';
    el('altitude').innerText = geolocation.getAltitude() + ' [m]';
    el('altitudeAccuracy').innerText = geolocation.getAltitudeAccuracy() + ' [m]';
    el('heading').innerText = geolocation.getHeading() + ' [rad]';
    el('speed').innerText = geolocation.getSpeed() + ' [m/s]';
  });

  // handle geolocation error.
  geolocation.on('error', function(error) {
    var info = document.getElementById('info');
    info.innerHTML = error.message;
    info.style.display = '';
  });

  var accuracyFeature = new Feature();
  geolocation.on('change:accuracyGeometry', function() {
    accuracyFeature.setGeometry(geolocation.getAccuracyGeometry());
  });

  var positionFeature = new Feature();
  positionFeature.setStyle(new Style({
    image: new CircleStyle({
      radius: 6,
      fill: new Fill({
        color: '#3399CC'
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 2
      })
    })
  }));

  geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
    var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
    positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
      new Point(coordinates) : null);
  });

  new VectorLayer({
    map: map,
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [accuracyFeature, positionFeature]
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The OpenLayers geolocation example should work if your browser/device combination is configured to support geolocation.  If it doesn't any other code will also not work.

Comment: Is possible to implement geolocation to openlayers Explorer?